# How to be treated as a Mopria Certified printer?

Tags: android, printing

I've developed an IPP server and am attempting to have it recognised as a printer by the Mopria Print Service on Android. Can anyone tell me how to respond to the request for these attributes?

mopria_certified
mopria-certified

Comment: side note: how to implement mopria discovery https://serverfault.com/questions/673035/mopria-and-dns-sd

Answer (score 2):

Mopria is short for Mopria Print Alliance. In order to have a Mopria Certified Printer, you need to belong to the Mopria organization, develop your printer or server to meet the Mopria specifications, and have the printer/print server certified. Contact Mopria at https://mopria.org/ and look under the About tab for a contact link.